# removing vectors from data frame by suffix in r

Tags: r, subset, suffix

Some vectors in data frame `have` include the suffix `_rc_1`. I want to remove these vectors from the data frame. I've tried several options and get errors that show I'm misunderstanding something. For example:

```
library(dplyr)
newdata <- subset(mydata, -contains("_rc_1"))
Error: No tidyselect variables were registered
```

I'm agnostic to how I solve the problem.

Perhaps this is done best with `grepl()` and a regular expression, but I'm struggling to implement a version that performs as planned here as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`contains` work with `dplyr`  If we need to use `subset` (a `base R` function), use `grep` which can take regex pattern and return either a numeric index or the column names itself as `select` argument in `subset` can take both as valid inputs

```
subset(mydata, select = grep("_rc_1", names(mydata), value = TRUE, invert = TRUE))
```

Also, there is `startsWith/endsWith` in `base R` for prefix/suffix matches

```
subset(mydata, select = names(mydata)[!endsWith(names(mydata), "_rc_1")])
```

---

In `dplyr`, the `select_helpers`   - `contains` works with `select`

```
library(dplyr)
mydata %>%
   select(-contains("_rc_1"))
```

Reproducible with built-in dataset 'iris'

```
data(iris)
head(subset(iris, select = names(iris)[!endsWith(names(iris), "Length")]))
iris %>%  
    select(-contains('Sepal')) %>%
    head
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R you can use `grepl` to get a logical vector with length equal to `ncol(mydata)` which is `TRUE` for column names ending in `_rc_1` (the $ ensures that _rc_1 comes at the end). Then after swapping the `TRUE`s and `FALSE`s with `!`, you can subset your data frame using `[]`.

```
newdata <- mydata[!grepl('_rc_1$', names(mydata))]
```